# Javascript Local storage with function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-storage

I have a translation feature that switches paragraphs from english to french using javascript at the click of a button. Now I manually grab pre-translated paragraphs using innerhtml.I want to store the users action using localStorage. If they click on the translation onclick event, it should automatically run the translate_fr function on every other page. I want to avoid having the user to have to re-translate the website everytime they load a new page.

I have no clue how to do this, with some sort of conditional statement If the user clicks translate_fr the other pages should run a script to repeat that function once they load the other pages and I assume this can be done if their initial choice is stored in the browser using localstorage.

```js
 function translate_fr(){
 
 document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = `Chez Coupe Lion, nous ne sommes qu'un chat établissement offrant une gamme complète de services du toilettage complet, de la baignade à l'embarquement.Vous et votre animal sera ravi de savoir que seul un professionnel, des produits naturels et biodégradables sont utilisés, tout les sensibilités ou les allergies ne seront pas un problème`;
 
}
```

```html
<button class="translate" type="button" onclick="translate_fr()">FR</button>

    <p id="intro">
      Here at Lion Kuts we are a cat only
      establishment that offers a full range of services 
      from complete grooming, bathing to boarding. You and 
      your pet will be thrilled to know that only professional, 
      natural and biodegradeable products are used, any 
      sensitivities or allergies will not be a problem.
  </p>
```

Comment: What you said in the first paragraph is quite confusing. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: If the default is English, simply do `localStorage.setItem("french", "yes");` when the user clicks the button. Then do `localStorage.removeItem("french");` when they switch back to English. And on every page, after it is loaded, simply check whether `localStorage.getItem("french") === "yes"` and translate the page if true.

Comment: To re-phrase and keep it simple, the user enters the site for the first time and chooses to translate the page to french. Now he goes to the second page, that translation should carry over to the next page. All pages load in english by default. I only want the translate_fr function to run on other pages if they chose to activate it at one point

Comment: I think what Chris G posted is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
function translate_fr() {
  document.getElementById(
    "intro"
  ).innerHTML = `Chez Coupe Lion, nous ne sommes qu'un chat établissement offrant une gamme complète de services du toilettage complet, de la baignade à l'embarquement.Vous et votre animal sera ravi de savoir que seul un professionnel, des produits naturels et biodégradables sont utilisés, tout les sensibilités ou les allergies ne seront pas un problème`;
  localStorage.setItem("isFrench", "1");
}

function translate_eng() {
  document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = `Here at Lion Kuts we are a cat only
  establishment that offers a full range of services 
  from complete grooming, bathing to boarding. You and 
  your pet will be thrilled to know that only professional, 
  natural and biodegradeable products are used, any 
  sensitivities or allergies will not be a problem.`;
  localStorage.setItem("isFrench", "0");
}

function check_translation() {
  const isFrench = localStorage.getItem("isFrench");
  return parseInt(isFrench);
}

function translate() {
  if (check_translation() === 1) {
    translate_fr();
    return;
  }

  translate_eng();
}

translate();
```

- Firing a function `translate()` on load.
- This could check local storage value `localStorage.getItem("isFrench");`.
- Local storage is strings, so converting to an int but not real need to do that.
- Which would be set when the users does your onClick
  event (which isn't in this example)
- If 1, display the French.
- If 0, display the English.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before posting an answer. The chances of this not being a duplicate is zero (this question is also not about the translation per se; a dark mode solution is a duplicate here, too)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate!

Comment: Yes, so why did you post an answer?

Comment: Been a while, wanted to help the OP :)

Comment: That is fine of course, but you'll help them, other users and the mods if you link to a suitable dupe instead ;)

Comment: ;) just a bit rusty, I'll remember to follow the process again!